Why is my player not colliding with animated obstacles?
I can't figure this out. My obstacles have a basic box collider on them and my player has a rigidbody based controller and collsion detection is set to Continous and when obstacle hits him it just passes trough the player. Belowe is my player rigidbody and collider settings
Update:
Ok so I found out the following things:
Player do seem to react a little when I add a rigidbody to the obstacle, set it to kinematic with continuous collision detection, and I increase player size (this is the most important change). Still it only moves slightly and obstacle passes trough the player.


How do you move your player? Have you manipulated the collision matrix?

I move it with rigidbody based controller using addforce and sometimes messing with velocity but it collision doesn't work even when I am not moving

Add a screenshot of your layer collision matrix, and tell us what layer your player and obstacles are on. If the obstacles are moving, they should have a Rigidbody. If they're animated with script or an Animator Controller, the Rigidbody on the obstacle should have "Is Kinematic" checked. Make sure the collider on the obstacles is not a trigger.

Collsion matrix is default so everything collides with everything. I did try kinematic but it behaves strange sometimes.

We can't do much to help you with only "it behaves strange sometimes". Please edit your question to walk us through the steps needed to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem, starting from an empty scene. Once we can reproduce the exact issues you're seeing, we can test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

How are your obstacles animated? It's very difficult to help when you're barely providing us with any information.

Using animator component.

If it passes through the obstacles, include the transform in your question. You might have made them too small and it just passes through in a step

Use a kinematic Rigidbody on the obstacle. Set the Animator Component's "Update Mode" to "Animate Physics".

As stated in the documentation, "You should use this mode if you are animating the motion of objects with physics interactions, such as characters which can push rigidbody
objects around."

This was it thankyou very much. Didn't know about this so it didn't occur to me to look at docs.

@Ivan You're welcome! Glad to help.
